# What is the purpose of views in SQL?

Tags: sql, view

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are views good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214132/what-are-views-good-for)

I'm trying to figure out what the purpose of views in an SQL database is?

Why, when and how would I create and use views?

Comment: dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214132/what-are-views-good-for

Answer (score 13):

- Many different perspectives of the same table.
- Can hide certain columns in a table. For example you may want to allow employees to see other employees' phone number column, but only certain employees to be able to access an employee's salary column!
- Can provide huge time savings in writing queries by already having a group of frequently accessed tables joined together in a view.
- Views allow you to use functions and manipulate data in ways that meet your requirements. For example, you store a person's birth date, but you like to calculate this to determine their age.

Answer (score 3):

It can be used to simplify complex joins that you use repeatedly across your DB.

```
CREATE view [dbo].[V_MyComplexJoin] 
As    
    Select TableA.A, TableB.B
    From TableA
        Inner Join TableB On TableA.BID = TableB.ID
```