# what is the use of view in sql server?

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are views good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214132/what-are-views-good-for)

hi,
   i have a doubt what is a view. where should we use and what is the use of view.
is there any good reference for views. thank you

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214132/what-are-views-good-for.  Please search for existing answers before asking a question.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278521/why-do-you-create-a-view-in-a-database

Comment: ok, actually i ask this question for good explanation

Comment: can we insert new rows in the views (can we write the insert query in views)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please, have an eye out this [View (database) Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(database)).

In short, a `View` can be used with more than SQL Server, it is a SQL Standard.

**A `VIEW` is generally used:**

1. To present the information data on a different point of *view*;
2. To simplify the access to the information of a high-level complexity of the database schema;
3. To prevent direct access to database tables (for security purposes)(less popular these days because of *ORM tools*);
4. Some "reality" is just simpler with a `VIEW`.

Here's an example when the database schema stores hierarchical data in multiple database tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicules (
    VId int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    , VDescription nvarchar(20) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE MotoredVehicules (
    MvId int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    , MvVId int NOT NULL REFERENCES Vehicules (VId)
    , MvMake nvarchar(20) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE MotorHP (
    MhpId int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    , MhpMvId int NOT NULL REFERENCES MotoredVehicules (MvId)
    , MhpHP decimal(6, 2) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE VehiculesWheels (
    VwId int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    , VwVId int NOT NULL REFERENCES Vehicules (VId)
    , VwNumberOfWheels int NOT NULL
)

insert into Vehicules (VDescription) values (N'Bicycle')
GO
insert into Vehicules (VDescription) values (N'Motorcycle')
GO
insert into Vehicules (VDescription) values (N'Automobile')
GO
insert into Vehicules (VDescription) values (N'Yacht')
GO

-- Inserting the information about the vehicules that have a motor.
insert into MotoredVehicules (MvVId, MvMake) (
    select v.VId
            , N'Harley Davidson'
        from Vehicules as v
        where v.VDescription LIKE N'Motorcycle'
)
GO
insert into MotoredVehicules (MvVId, MvMake) (
    select v.VId
            , N'Sea-Ray'
        from Vehicules as v
        where v.VDescription LIKE N'Yacht'
)
GO
insert into MotoredVehicules (MvVId, MvMake) (
    select v.VId
            , N'Mercedes'
        from Vehicules as v
        where v.VDescription LIKE N'Automobile'
)
GO

-- Inserting motor HP for the motorized vehicules.
insert into MotorHP (MhpMvId, MhpHP) (
    select mv.MvId
            , 350
        from MotoredVehicules as mv
        where mv.MvMake LIKE N'Sea-Ray'
)
GO
insert into MotorHP (MhMvId, MhpHP) (
    select mv.MvId
            , 280
        from MotoredVehicules as mv
        where mv.MvMake LIKE N'Mercedes'
)
GO
insert into MotorHP (MhpMvId, MhpHP) (
    select mv.MvId
            , 930
        from MotoredVehicules as mv
        where mv.MvMake LIKE N'Harley Davidson'
)
GO

-- Inserting the number of wheels for wheeled vehicules.
insert into VehiculesWheels (VwVId, VwNumberOfWheels) (
    select v.VId
            , 2
        from Vehicules as v
        where v.VDescription IN (N'Bicycle', N'Motorcycle')
)
GO
insert into VehiculesWheels (VwVId, VwNumberOfWheels) (
    select v.VId
            , 4
        from Vehicules as v
        where v.VDescription LIKE N'Automobile'
)
GO
```

This relational model is not very comprehensive by itself. We could have used one only table to insert them all with all of their specifications, and let *NULL* the fields with no data. However, because of some hierarchy reasons, we have created tables for specifications about different type of *Vehicules*. Thus, when you want to have the information about vehicule in particular, it is not very practical, as you have to join the tables every now and then you have to retrieve the information. Here, it could become practical to have a *View* like so:

```
CREATE VIEW WheeledMotoredVehiculesView AS
    select v.VId
            , mv.MvMake
            , hp.MhpHP
            , vw.NumberOfWheels
            , v.VDescription
        from Vehicules as v
            left join MotoredVehicules as mv on mv.MvVId = v.VId
            left join MotorHP as hp on hp.MhpMvId on mv.MvId
            left join VehiculesWheels as vw on vw.VwVId = v.VId
GO

CREATE VIEW MotoredVehiculesView AS
    select v.VId
            , mv.MvMake
            , hp.MhpHP
            , v.VDescription
        from Vehicules as v
            left join MotoredVehicules as mv on mv.MvId = v.Id
            left join MotorHP as hp on hp.MhpMvId = mv.MvId
GO

CREATE VIEW WheeledVehicules AS
    select v.VId
            , vw.NumberOfWheels
            , v.VDescription
        from Vehicules as v
            left join VehiculesWheels vw on vw.VwVId = v.VId
GO
```

Then, instead of having to write the *select* contained within each of both above-created views each time you need to access some information data about a given vehicule, you simply query against the appropriate *view* itself:

```
select *
    from MotoredVehiculesView
```

Or whatever information you need.

***Disclaimer:*** This code has not been tested and was written directly for example purposes only. It might not work as-is.

I hope this helps you better understand *views*, somehow.

Comment: Old but still relevant, and the example is very good about explaining a practical use case, i.e representing complex queries that can be stored in a view. But remember a view does not store anything, it is populated dynamically from the real database when querying the view.

Answer (score 4):

Views are essentially "Queries" that you can select from without touching the main tables.

Any select query that you normally do (multiple tables, functions, etc.) could be a view.

There are two main advantages of views.

The first is that they allow you to reuse common ways of looking at the data without having to write the same complex SQL over and over (ie, modularization).

The second is that you can tighten security on the source tables for the particular user while allowing them to see the data through the views.

Comment: if i write the view on emp table. suppose if the emp table consist 5 rows and i create a view. and i inserted a new row in emp table then the newly created row will display in the view?

Comment: Yes.  Behind the scenes the view will always be run on the source table every time you use it.

Comment: ok, so views are used for security of the base table

Comment: can we apply update query for  the views

Comment: RE: "the view will always be run on the source table every time you use it" There are Materialised/Indexed Views in some implementations that muddy the waters a bit here.

Comment: Yes.  Materialized views are a different beast.  
I do believe some views can be updated but I'm not sure to what extent.

Comment: if we changse the base table structure it will reflect on the views

Comment: It's not automatic, you might have to adapt the view.
In postgreSQL you can get the effect of an updatable view by creating rules that rewrite inserts, etc. on the view into appropriate actions on other tables.
Information is found on the following links:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createview.html
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createrule.html

Answer (score 3):

See [Views in SQL Server](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dev/views_in_sql_server_p1.aspx) for a good overview.

> A view is a virtual table that
>   consists of columns from one or more
>   tables. Though it is similar to a
>   table, it is not stored in the database.
>   It is a query stored as an object.
>   Hence, a view is an object that
>   derives its data from one or more
>   tables. These tables are referred to
>   as base or underlying tables.

Comment: if i delete one of the column of base table then what about the view

Comment: @Surya - your view won't work if you delete an underlying column... you'll have to edit your view to match the new schema.

Comment: can we write insert query on views?