# How to use VIEWS in SQL Queries

Tags: sql-server, view

We have third party software that installed SQL database so we can create custom queries.

They also have views which includes values, such as VIRUSNAME that the Tables does not have.

So far, I find tutorials on how to create views, but where do I find tutorials on how to use views in an SQL query?

[image]

Comment: `Select * From dbo.V_VIRUS` ?

Comment: Use them exactly like a table?  I don't understand your question.

Comment: you don't have to do anything special on views. just treat them like a table. in some, but definitely not all cases, you can even `update` a view, but generally you just `select * from someview where ...` like you would with any other "normal" table.

Comment: A tutorial I found: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-views.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, take a look in this interesting post [What are views good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/214132/771579)

**SQL CREATE VIEW Syntax**

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
```

**Calling a VIEW**

```
SELECT * FROM [Name of your VIEW]
```

Finally, I can give you this basic link [Introduction to Sql Server Views](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/127726/Introduction-to-Sql-Server-Views)

Comment: I tried this, but I didn't try putting brackets around the VIEW

Comment: @Glowie are you saying the square brackets fixed your issue? as they are optional?!

Comment: @Tanner first time I tried without brackets it didn't work. But now I tried after reading your comment and it worked. Perhaps I did something else in MS SQL Server, because I was agonizing over this for a while

Comment: So the issue was a typo with your syntax?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at [a tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-views.htm)  from TutorialsPoint.

Contains most of the things you need to know about views.

A few more are:

[From code project: How to create,update,delete a view](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/639239/Creating-and-Usage-of-View-in-SQL)

[From w3 schools:How to create,update,delete a view(with great examples)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp)

[From microsoft technet:Scenarios for Using Views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms188250(v=sql.105).aspx)

> ## Use of a View
>
> Views are generally used to focus, simplify, and customize the
>   perception each user has of the database.Views can be used for
>   security purposes because they provide encapsulation of the name of
>   the table. Data is in the virtual table, not stored permanently. Views
>   display only selected data.
>
> The syntax for **creating a View** is given below:
>
> ```
> Create View Viewname As
>  Select Column1, Column2  From Tablename   Where (Condition) Group by (Grouping Condition) having (having Condition) For example:
>
>  Create View View_Employeeinfo As s
>     Select EmpId, EmpName, employmentdate  From EmployeeInfo
> ```
>
> Now user can use the view View_EmployeeInfo as a table to get the
>   empid, empname and employmentdate information of the employees by
>   using the following query:
>
> ```
>  Select  *   from  View_EmployeeInfo  where empid=3
> ```
>
> #### Others uses:
>
> 1. Views let users focus on specific data that interests them and on the specific tasks for which they are responsible. Unnecessary or
>      sensitive data can be left out of the view.
> 2. Views can simplify how users work with data. You can define frequently used joins, projections, UNION queries, and SELECT queries
>      as views so that users do not have to specify all the conditions and
>      qualifications every time an additional operation is performed on that
>      data.
> 3. Views enable you to create a backward compatible interface for a table when its schema changes.
> 4. Views let different users to see data in different ways, even when they are using the same data at the same time.
> 5. Views can be used to export data to other applications.
> 6. The Transact-SQL UNION set operator can be used within a view to combine the results of two or more queries from separate tables into a
>      single result set. This appears to the user as a single table that is
>      called a partitioned view.

Comment: link only answer x4. If you're posting links, provide some key information from the link that helps actually answer the question as the link may change or die.

Comment: Ok, minor thing, if you're quoting text you should use the Blockquotes formatting tool to highlight the text as a quote, or state that it is from the links.

Answer (score -2):

Well, you use the views to fetch data just like the way you do the same from tables.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0160__View/Performselectoncolumnsinaview.htm

hope this is what you wanted!

Comment: link only answer. If you're posting links, provide some key information from the link that helps actually answer the question as the link may change or die.

Comment: Also, this link is for Oracle and the question is on SQL Server