# Postgres Concating a 2 columns in create table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a table

for example i want the column "test3 " to be test1/test2) so therefore the table would look like

test3 int = test1/test2

`create table test (test1 int, test2 int, test3 int ??);`

Comment: Are you using PostgreSql or MySql? Please only select the DBMS you're using. This sounds like it should be a view and not a table.

Comment: Looks like you want a generated column. They exist in both [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html) and [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) but the syntax differs

Answer (score 1):

A typical way to handle values calculated from table values is to include them in a view.  See also: [What are views good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214132/what-are-views-good-for).

So, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE test(test1 INTEGER, test2 INTEGER);
```

followed by

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test_v AS
SELECT
  test1,
  test2,
  test1/test2 AS test3
FROM test
```

You would then query the view exactly as you would your proposed table.  It behaves similarly to a table in terms of syntax, but the rows of the view are just pulled from the table; they aren't stored elsewhere in the database.  And `test3` is not stored anywhere, it's simply calculated when needed.

One last thing: when dividing you should always ensure no division by zero.  How to avoid that depends on whether `test2` is the kind of thing that should never be zero, or might sometimes be zero.  If it shouldn't, then that check can be built right into the table:

```
CREATE TABLE test(test1 INTEGER, test2 INTEGER CHECK (test2 <> 0));
```

If instead you might possibly want to allow `test2` to be zero, then a better way might be to account for it in the view with a case statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test_v AS
SELECT
  test1,
  test2,
  CASE test2 WHEN 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE test1/test2 END AS test3
FROM test
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create it as a generated column:

```
create table test 
(
  test1 int, 
  test2 int, 
  test3 int generated always as ( test1 / nullif(test2, 0) ) stored
);
```

Note that this uses integer division, so e.g. `1/3` will yield `0`. If you don't want that, you need to define the generated column as `numeric` and cast the values to `numeric` in the division.

But why store a value that can be calculated very cheaply while retrieving the data, e.g. using a view as Eli Johnson suggested.