# i created a mysql table from another table but the but values are not refreshing

Tags: mysql

I created a totals table which is a summation of column of another table but when i add another entry in the parent table the totals table is not changing below is my sql quey

```
\\
CREATE TABLE emphayatotals  AS

SELECT 

SUM(available_for_use_month)
,SUM(available_for_use_today)
,SUM(expected_tomorrow)
,SUM(expected_before_monthend)

FROM emphayas;
```

I tried creating the table ussing As but still not changing the totals in the total table even if i refresh

Comment: 'parent table' ? I think what you want is a view. Logically the only way to do what you're describing is with a view, or using triggers on the source table(s).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are views good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214132/what-are-views-good-for)

Comment: Think about it! Once you do this and create a new table, within seconds it is likely to be Out of Date as something will have changed on `emphayas`

Comment: @RiggsFolly so you saying there is nothing wrong with my code

Comment: NO! I am saying DONT DO THAT!! Do as @AD7six suggested and create a VIEW. Then when you `select from viewname` you will get the correct results EVERY TIME you look

Comment: A create..select is a one off event..ie the created table cannot 'see' changes in the parent nor can you define columns in a table which access another table. Generally speaking unless there are performance issues it's better to calculate on demand rather than store. This is why you are being steered towards a view..having said that a view may not be appropriate for you but without more detail I'm not seeing a viable alternative.